# Check-boxes and Arrays

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

```
<tr>
<td width=60%><asp:CheckBox ID="chk0" runat="server" /> ...</td>
<td width=40%><asp:CheckBox ID="chk1" runat="server" /> ...</td>
</tr>
...
...
...
```

I have values coming in like this:

```
var lst = "18,6,0,7,0,4,0,1,5,0,2"
```

If 18 is there then chk18 is checked and ect... 0 just means no getting checked. Is there an ideal way to code this? whileloop be ideal?

The values are coming from a database table all the data is in that format.

Comment: What do you mean with 0? You have also chk0... and 0 appears multiple times in your list...

Comment: This is a little confusing. You're saying the first number (18) means the checkbox with id "chk18" should get checked, but 0 means nothing is getting checked? What about the checkbox with id "chk0"

Comment: Use a [`CheckBoxList` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx)? Or a [`Repeater` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, this will not work for your control 'chk0' and will blow up if you don't have a correlating checkbox (ex = 18 is in your data, but you have no control chk18).

```
    Dim strData As String = "18,6,0,7,0,4,0,1,5,0,2"

    Dim lstIDs As List(Of String) = strData.Split(",").ToList()

    For Each strID As Integer In lstIDs

        If CInt(strID) > 0 Then

            CType(Page.FindControl("chk" & strID), CheckBox).Checked = True

        End If

    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you mean about the value of "0" since you have a control with an id of 0.  Anyway, I haven't done ASP.NET WebForms in awhile, but this will get you well on your way:

```
var lst = "18,6,0,7,0,4,0,1,5,0,2"
var checkboxIdsToBeSelected = lst.Split(',');

foreach (var id in checkboxIdsToBeSelected) {
    foreach (Control ctrl in Page.Controls) {
        if (ctrl is CheckBox && cntrl.ID == "chk" + id) {
          ((CheckBox)(ctrl)).Checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although he has used `var` instead of `Dim`, he has tagged it VB.NET instead of C#.

Comment: Should be easy enough to convert if needed.